# Click inside then in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

```js
cy.get("tbody > tr")
  .first()
  .then((el) => {
    console.log(el);
    el.get("td.edit > button").click();
  });
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
         Lorem ipsum
      </td>
      <td class="edit">
        <button>Button</button>
      </td>
      <td>
         Lorem ipsum
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above code snippet is from my cypress test where I want to click the button of the first `<tr>` tag.

The above test codes the following error.

How can I perform click() operation inside then block ?

> Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `cy.wrap()`

```
cy.get("tbody > tr")
  .first()
  .then((el) => {
    cy.wrap(el).find("td.edit > button").click();
  });
```